# Lazyload load all images after on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

**See this url:** [click here](http://dev.cmyuk.com/player/)

The video placeholder images are loading using lazyload.

It works fine as you scroll down the page, but if you click on the filter options the images which are further down the page do not load until you scroll again.

**For example follow these steps...**

Load page, then with out scrolling click on the "Misc" filter. You will see the second image does not load.

I have tried adding the below code. However nothing happens. Why is this?

```
$(document).on('click', '#portfolio-filter a', function() {

            alert("clicked!");

            $("img.lazy").lazyload({
                bind: "event",
                delay: 0
            });

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onclick event just call the lazyload function to trigger the load, like if you were triggering another event, call the function without parameters:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#portfolio-filter a', function() {

    alert("clicked!");

    $("img.lazy").lazyload();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the alert() doesn't happen at the moment either?